# use jQuery to select option from menu based on its text not value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select menu like this

```
<select>
   <option value="1234567">one</option>
   <option value="7654321">two</option>
</select>
```

I need to select an option that has its text equal to `'one'` (this is dynamic and changes so I need to be able to always select option that is related to some sort of text) therefore something like `$('select option[value="one"]').prop('selected', true);` doesn't work for me as it looks at value attribute instead of text.

Comment: Use `$('select option:contains("one")')`

Comment: @Imgonzales was working on it as you comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
$('select option:contains("one")')
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

As @George notes, beware that it matches *any* result *containing* `one`, including ones with the word `stone`.

```js
document.write($('select option:contains("one")').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="123456">one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Bare in mind that `contains()` won't match the text within the option exactly, `:contains("one")`, for example will match an option with the text 'stone': http://jsfiddle.net/794wn7o4/

Answer (score 1):

While `:contains()` is a valid solution to the case above, it does exactly what you'd expect: matches an element that *contains* the parameter, not equals it.

`:contains("one")` would match `<option>stone</option>` as well as `<option>one</option>`.

To filter by exact text within, you can use `.filter()`:

```
var val = $('select option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'one';
}).val();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/794wn7o4/1/)